# Add a rollover effect to a MigLayout table

Tags: java, swing, rollover, miglayout

I want to add a rollover effect to the current row of a table layered with MigLayout.
I guess the best way is to overwrite paintComponent() adding a rectangle fill for the current row bounds.
I can iterate over the  table components and ask them for their bounds but, how can I get the bounds of a row?

[image]

**EDIT**

It seems I finally managed to solve this issue. Unfortunately the solution I found is too cumbersome -something like adding a image to your first post- and impractical for most users, so I feel it's not worth to mention here. I'm still looking forward for a natural procedure.

[image]

Comment: good question :-) In your shoes I would look into the source and see how those debug lines grab the cell bounds (the red are the cell bounds, afair). Then try to do the same in your custom code

Comment: @kleopatra Unfortunately it seems that Miglayout don't export some state that is relevant here, or at least I didn't be able to identify it. So no way but incorporate the sources in the project and make some hacks on them.